# How to run program from another folder in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm in `E:\blah\blah` but I need to run an .exe from `E:\folder name\prgm.exe`

However, I am trying to call this without having to do `cd ..`

I read that just typing `E:\folder name\prgm.exe` should work.  However when I try this I get an error:

> E:\folder is not recognized as an external or internal command.

I'm running Windows 7 if that helps.

Answer (score 29):

`E:\folder name\prgm.exe` works if the folder name has no space in it.

Either:

1. Rename the folder so it has no space.
2. Use quotes. (e.g. `"E:\folder name\prgm.exe"`)
3. Or add E:\folder name to the path.

Use option 3) if it is an often used program.
Use option 2) for single or rare invokations.

Comment: Thank you! I had originally tried moving it into a folder without a space, but it wasn't working since the command required an input file argument, for which I was forgetting the E:\... in front of that as well.  I couldn't do the quotes since i was running this command from MATLAB which itself required quotes for syntax purposes.  Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to add the folder to the path

Answer (score 12):

The reason that you get the error

> E:\folder is not recognized as an external or internal command.

is because the system thinks that your folder name is "folder" since what is after the space would be a place to put a flag such as -t or -l .
Whenever you have a space in the name of a file or a folder (not really a good practice, you can use a - or an _ to separate words in the name) you should use double quotation marks around the entire name, this includes the filename and its extension.
If there is a flag or an option to the command it would have to be outside of the quotation marks example, from you blah blah folder

```
E:\blah\blah>"E:\folder name\prgm.exe" -t -l 1000
```

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: That was my first intention but due to a low number of rep points I couldn't comment, that's why I had to write a reply.

Comment: I understand **why** you did it. But please don't do that.

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness' sake, I would like to note that in addition to [Hennes'](https://superuser.com/a/490159/77396) answer, there is a [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582002/653295) option, though in fact you might find it too similar to `cd`:

Enter `pushd E:\folder name` and your working directory changes to the specified drive and folder (no quotes required) in one easy step; returning to the previous working directory is a no-brainer as well with a simple `popd`…

Comment: This solved my problem (thanks mousio) `pushd %~dp0`, then ... execute whatever, then `popd`